# Update column based on year of another column in postgresql using a trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a trigger to update the column reminder(datatype date) using the data of the column date_of_join(datatype date) of same table. Reminder should be 1st of January, next year.

My function is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_reminder()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
NEW."reminder" := make_date(CAST (extract(year from timestamp NEW."date_of_join") AS INTEGER) ,2,3);
RETURN NEW;
END 
$$ LANGUAGE 
plpgsql;
```

My trigger is :

```
CREATE TRIGGER "Trigger1"
BEFORE INSERT ON faculty
for each row
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_reminder();
```

It is giving me error : syntax error at or near "NEW"

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`date_trunc` can be used to round to the beginning of the year; then you can add 1 year to arrive at January first of the following year:

```
NEW.reminder := date_trunc('year', NEW.date_of_join) + INTERVAL '1 year';
```